# Creating simple registration form via jQuery and SpringBoot

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot

Good evening. I am trying to create a simple registration form using jQuery 3.2.1 and SpringBoot 2.0.7. (Giving you all the information you can possibly need). Throws an exception "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at bootstrap.min.js:6".

So this is my html code(in header there are scripts which input bootstrap 3.3.7 and jQuery 3.2.1): `

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>FG - Sign up</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href="signupcss.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id = "main">

           <div id = "block1" class = "container-fluid">

              <div id="block1middle" class = "container-fluid">
               <h1>Registration</h1>
               <form action="#" name = "newUserForm" autocomplete="email">
               <p>Your email:<input type="text" name = "inputEmail"></p><br>
               <p>Password: 
               <input type="password" name = "inputPassword">
               </p>
               <button form="newUserForm" type="submit" id = "saveNewUser" ><p>Submit</p></button>
               </form>
               </div>

           </div>
             <script>
                 $('#saveNewUser').click(function(){
                     var emailVar = $('inputEmail').val();
                 var passwordVar = $('inputPassword').val();
                var newUser = {
                  "email": emailVar,
                "password": passwordVar,
                };
               $.ajax({
                   'url' : 'http://localhost:8080/users/save',
                   'type' : 'PUT',
                   'contentType' : 'application/json',
                   'dataType': 'json',
                   'data' : JSON.stringify(newUser),
                   'success' : function(data){
                       alert(data)
                   },
                   'error': function(error){
                       console.log(error);
                   }
               });
                 })

           </script>

   </div>

</body>
</html>`
```

There is my localhost:8080/users/save UserController:

```
`     
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


    @PutMapping("/save")
    public void save(@RequestBody UserRequest userRequest){
        userService.save(userRequest);
    }

}      '
```

And UserRequest just has two fields: email and password(with getters and setters). UserService's method "save" just checks for an originality of an email and saves new User. 
I am grateful about any help or critics! Thank you. 
P.S. I am very beginner in programming so I will be very grateful about any useful links about this topic.

Comment: I believe you should be importing jquery.js before you import bootstrap.js in your head

Answer (score 4, accepted):

let me try and point out whatever I can that might help:

The reason you're getting that error is because, in your , you have imported your scripts in the wrong order. Since you import bootstrap first (which depends on jquery) you get that error.

**Original:**

```
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Updated:**

```
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Next, although the code you have there should work, since you're using a form, you can actually modify it to make the call for you

```
<form action="PUT" target="/users/save" name="newUserForm" autocomplete="email">
```

This will call the target of **/users/save** and pass in your email / password <strike>in the body (the keys of which are defined by the **name** field in your inputs.</strike> as url params. Example:

```
<form action="#" name = "newUserForm" autocomplete="email">
  <p>Your email: <input type="text" name = "inputEmail"></p><br>
  <p>Password: <input type="password" name = "inputPassword"></p>
  <button form="newUserForm" type="submit" id = "saveNewUser" > 
  <p>Submit</p></button>
</form>
```

**/users/save?inputEmail=useremail&inputPassword=userpass**

This can be accessed in Spring Boot via

```
@PutMapping("/save")
public void save(@Param("inputEmail" String email, @Param("inputPassword") String password) {
    //...
}
```

Now, if you'd like to pass it as JSON using javascript, you can follow what @Keetch said and you'll only have to make the edit of adding an id field to your email / password (you can replace the name field, but you wont' be able to access it through the form)

```
<form action="#" name = "newUserForm" autocomplete="email">
  <p>Your email: <input type="text" name = "inputEmail" id="inputEmail"></p><br>
  <p>Password: <input type="password" name = "inputPassword" id="inputPassword"></p>
  <button form="newUserForm" type="submit" id = "saveNewUser" > 
  <p>Submit</p></button>
</form>
```

and now you can access their values through

```
var emailVar = $('#inputEmail').val();
var passwordVar = $('#inputPassword').val();
```

**notice the extra # in front which indicates you're looking for an id**
When using $(), "#name" looks for an id, ".name" looks for a class, and "name" looks for an element with that value

In the spirit of other improvements, since your intention is a RESTful API, there are a few things that could be done to be a little truer to REST.

1. this call should be a POST instead of a PUT. A POST is a call that is not idempotent whereas PUT is. This means that if you make a PUT call once or multiple times and the outcome will be the same. Whereas, a POST may result in multiple outcomes if called more than once. Even though technically you can only create one user for one email, it would fall more under a POST than a PUT. PUT is usually used for updating an object (note: by supplying the entire object. If you want to update part of an object you can use PATCH)
2. REST endpoints work based on VERB / NOUN patterns. Meaning POST USER would mean "create user." this would render the extra **/save** part of your URL to be redundant. I would recommend removing that since POST is essentially a save.
3. it is usually common practice to load your javascript depdencies at the bottom of your page instead of the top of the page to allow it to load quicker. You have your inline scripts at the bottom, which is good, so you might want to consider moving the dependencies to right above your  tag at the bottom.
4. I'm not going to address the saving of passwords in plaintext because that a whole different topic. But it should be noted that one should never plan to use plaintext passwords in production :)
5. Since you're already using the wonderful spring boot, maybe you'd want to consider using Spring Security -- You can find a great tutorial here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-thymeleaf
6. And finally, I see you are trying to use Bootstrap, but it looks like you're not actually using any of the bootstrap UI elements. First, if it's not a requirement of the project, I'd suggest using Bootstrap 4 as it's been out for a while now and is the newest version. Second, you can find a nice and simple bootstrap sign-in page here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/

Comment: Thank you for your help! Now it doesn't throw this error, but 500 :)  I added action and target to my form tag. Also I changed put to post everywhere. Either with or without action and target, it doesn't work. Can you help me saying where should I look for a mistake at least?

Comment: I included your given solution in my post and gave an explanation for it. I also corrected my mentioning of using the form action. It actually sends the data as query params, and not in a body.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: 
switch "name" attribute to id, add "#" to inputEmail and inputPassword. Also don't forget to import scripts in the right order.

> The reason you're getting that error is because, in your , you have imported your scripts in the wrong order. Since you import bootstrap first (which depends on jquery) you get that error.
>
> AKrush95

```
                 $('#saveNewUser').click(function(){
                 var emailVar = $('#inputEmail').val();
             var passwordVar = $('#inputPassword').val();
            var newUser = {
              "email": emailVar,
            "password": passwordVar,
            };
```